# Looping for a value in a userform textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to write a basic loop that finds a unique value in a specific column in my worksheet. I believe that I have declared my variables properly. However, when I attempt to run my code, it gives me an overflow error. All I want is for my macro to be able to loop through my data set until it finds the specific ID Number.

Below is my Code for facilitated viewing:

```
Sub Macro1()  
    Dim FirstRow As Range
    Dim LastRow As Range
    Dim R As Long

    FirstRow = Worksheets("Petrobras").Range("V2")
    LastRow = Worksheets("Petrobras").Cells(Rows.Count, 22).End(xlUp).Select
    R = TXTOPPNUM_Insert.Value

    For R = FirstRow To LastRow
        Worksheets("Petrobras").Cells(Rows.Count, 22).Find(R, , , Lookat:=xlWhole).Select
    Next R
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure why you're looping here. Sounds like you just need to `Find`.

Comment: Some mistakes really. You are looping `R` as `Long` datatype, but you have made `FirstRow` a `Range` variable, which you incorrectly set. Same goes for `LastRow`. Then I assume you'll end up having more issues along the line. I don't think you should have a `OverFlow` error in the first place, your code won't reach further than `FirstRow = ....`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what may help:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim FirstRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim R As Long
Dim tempStore As New collection ' collection is initialized with .Count = 0
Dim uniqueValue As Variant

' is that needed?
'R = TXTOPPNUM_Insert.Value

With Worksheets("Petrobras")

    FirstRow = .Cells(2, 22).row ' set first row
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 22).End(xlUp).row ' set last row


    For R = FirstRow To LastRow ' there's an actual loop
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(range(.Cells(FirstRow, 22), .Cells(LastRow, 22)), .Cells(R, 22).Value) = 1 Then ' don't think that I have to explain how does the CountIf works
            tempStore.Add .Cells(R, 22).Value ' if the CountIf of value = 1 then adding this value to a collection
        End If
    Next

    If tempStore.Count > 1 Then ' if collection contains more that 1 value - means that there is not one unique value
        MsgBox "There is more then 1 unique value"
    Else
        uniqueValue = tempStore(1) ' if collection contains 1 value - assign the unique value variable
    End If

End With


End Sub
```

Also, look carefully to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) and [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement).

Answer (score 0):

To keep your code simple, you can use a one-liner that can be activated using a Button_Click on your userform; just add this line of code to the Button_Click macro. Type the value you are looking for into the textbox and click the button.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Petrobras").Range("V2", Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Find(What:=Me.TXTOPPNUM_Insert.Value).Select
```